# Get animate().translation Callback When Animation Is Complete

Tags: java, android, animation, callback, translate-animation

I've been looking around and the main ways seem to be setting an animation listener on the object. However I have set an animation listener and the animation complete callback does not fire.

Do you know how I can get the callback when an view.animate().translationY() has finished its animation?

```
root.setLayoutAnimationListener
        (
                new Animation.AnimationListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
                    {
                        closeFragmentAnimationComplete(); //is not called
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
                    {

                    }
                }
        );

root.animate().translationY(100);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```java
view.animate().translationY(100).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                closeFragmentAnimationComplete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
        });
```